# How to get all values in one column in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create a method that return with all values in the selected column in mysql
so can anyone tell me the used method in java

this method returns with just the first value in the column ::

```
public ArrayList<String> GetChair(String Class) throws SQLException{

   openconnection();
   String querychair = "SELECT * FROM hema.flight_usa WHERE free = 1 and class='"+Class+"'";
   Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();

   ResultSet rs;
   rs = stm.executeQuery(querychair);

   if(rs.next()){

      arr.add(rs.getString("chair_id"));           
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: repeat arr.add(rs.getString("chair_id")); and add all to arr or use metadata for dynamic solution

Comment: Replace `if` with `while`.

Comment: @HannoBinder op only want to get first value

Comment: @fastsnail Judging from "return with all values in the selected column" I don't think so. -- What's missing from the OP's code is also the `final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();`, by the way.

Comment: @HannoBinder ohh i was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(rs.next())
{
    arr.add(rs.getString("chair_id"));

}
```

This gives you the value of the first column for all the rows in your `rs`

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment says, you are reading the values in the if statement. That will only return the first result, if there is anything in the result set. Read it in a while loop, until the result set is empty.